# Is there a way to use PowerShell to enable "Run this resource in a separate resource monitor" in Advanced Policies in the Failover Cluster Manager?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, failovercluster, san

I have to change a large amount of VM's to run in their own rhs and the only way I can do this is in the advanced policies in the failover cluster manager, I need to find a way to set this to enabled via PowerShell so that it can be done quickly on all future VM's.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Get-ClusterResource “Resource Name”).SeparateMonitor = 1

Never mind I worked it out it is the above command. :)

Comment: be sure to read and understand this blog post. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2013/01/24/understanding-how-failover-clustering-recovers-from-unresponsive-resources/ I wonder why you "have to" change it. Could you explain this?